# How to know when a session closes?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to know when a user closes out of a session. This includes if multiple tabs are open. Only to record 1 session close if that happens.

If this possible? How using react-hooks?

If tried the below in App.js. Is there a more effective way to solve this solution?

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    console.log(props.current);
  };
}, [props.current]);
```

Comment: Is this what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing